# A non-nilpotent transformation $A$ of a vector space $V$ such that for every $v\in V$ there exist a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $A^n(v)=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Give an example of a vector space $V$ (dim$V$ may or may not be infinite) and a transformation $A$ of $V$ such that $A$ is NOT nilpotent and for every vector $v\in V$ there exist a natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $A^n(v)=0$.

I really don't have any clue on how to approach this problem.

Comment: is $V$ finite dimensional ?

Comment: @Surb That depends on the type of example you try to provide. The dimensionality of $V$ is allowed to be infinite but does not have to be.

Comment: For finite dimension you can take vectors from identity matrix and to consider that $A^nI$ is equal to $A^n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an infinite-dimensional vector space, the classical example is the left shift operator on $\{(a_1,a_2,\ldots):a_i\in\mathbb R,0=a_k=a_{k+1}=\cdots\text{ for some } k\}$ (the vector space of all sequences of real numbers with finitely many nonzero entries).

For a finite-dimensional vector space, no counterexamples exist. Given the assumption on $A$, when $n$ is sufficiently large, $A^n$ is zero on a basis of $V$. Therefore $A^n=0$ on $V$ and $A$ is nilpotent.